# How do I detect collision in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, pygame-surface, pygame2

I have made a list of bullets and a list of sprites using the classes below. How do I detect if a bullet collides with a sprite and then delete that sprite and the bullet?

```
#Define the sprite class
class Sprite:

    def __init__(self,x,y, name):
        self.x=x

        self.y=y

        self.image = pygame.image.load(name)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def render(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y))


# Define the bullet class to create bullets          
class Bullet:

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x + 23
        self.y = y
        self.bullet = pygame.image.load("user_bullet.BMP")
        self.rect = self.bullet.get_rect()

    def render(self):
        window.blit(self.bullet, (self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: I would notes that there is a Sprite Class in pygame - I am not sure redefining it in your code is a good idea. Besides are they really targets (for want of a better word), as a sprite is simply an object with a graphical representation on screen (and therefore your Bullet is a sprite too).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In PyGame, collision detection is done using [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects. The `Rect` object offers various methods for detecting collisions between objects. Even the collision between a rectangular and circular object such as a paddle and a ball can be detected by a collision between two rectangular objects, the paddle and the bounding rectangle of the ball.

Some examples:

- [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint):

  > Test if a point is inside a rectangle

  <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-collidepoint](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-collidepoint#main.py)</kbd>

  [image]

  ```py
  import pygame

  pygame.init()
  window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
  rect = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(100, 100)

  run = True
  while run:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              run = False

      point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      collide = rect.collidepoint(point)
      color = (255, 0, 0) if collide else (255, 255, 255)

      window.fill(0)
      pygame.draw.rect(window, color, rect)
      pygame.display.flip()

  pygame.quit()
  exit()
  ```
- [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

  > Test if two rectangles overlap

  See also [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152)

  <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-colliderect](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-colliderect#main.py)</kbd>

  [image: colliderect]

  ```py
  import pygame

  pygame.init()
  window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
  rect1 = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(75, 75)
  rect2 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 75, 75)

  run = True
  while run:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              run = False

      rect2.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      collide = rect1.colliderect(rect2)
      color = (255, 0, 0) if collide else (255, 255, 255)

      window.fill(0)
      pygame.draw.rect(window, color, rect1)
      pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), rect2, 6, 1)
      pygame.display.flip()

  pygame.quit()
  exit()
  ```

Furthermore, [`pygame.Rect.collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) and [`pygame.Rect.collidelistall`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall) can be used for the collision test between a rectangle and a list of rectangles. [`pygame.Rect.collidedict`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidedict) and [`pygame.Rect.collidedictall`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidedictall) can be used for the collision test between a rectangle and a dictionary of rectangles.

The collision of [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) objects, can be detected by [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide), [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) or [`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany). When using these methods, the collision detection algorithm can be specified by the `collided` argument:

> The collided argument is a callback function used to calculate if two sprites are colliding.

Possible `collided` callables are [`collide_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect), [`collide_rect_ratio`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio), [`collide_circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle), [`collide_circle_ratio`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle_ratio), [`collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

Some examples:

- [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide)

  <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-spritecollide](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-spritecollide#main.py)</kbd>

  [image]

  ```py
  import pygame

  pygame.init()
  window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))

  sprite1 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
  sprite1.image = pygame.Surface((75, 75))
  sprite1.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
  sprite1.rect = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(75, 75)
  sprite2 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
  sprite2.image = pygame.Surface((75, 75))
  sprite2.image.fill((0, 255, 0))
  sprite2.rect = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(75, 75)

  all_group = pygame.sprite.Group([sprite2, sprite1])
  test_group = pygame.sprite.Group(sprite2)

  run = True
  while run:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              run = False

      sprite1.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1, test_group, False)

      window.fill(0)
      all_group.draw(window)
      for s in collide:
          pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), s.rect, 5, 1)
      pygame.display.flip()

  pygame.quit()
  exit()
  ```

For a collision with masks, see [How can I make a collision mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043600/how-can-i-made-a-collision-mask/56045037#56045037) or [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039)

See also [Collision and Intersection](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_collision_and_intesection.md)

- [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) / [`collide_circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

  <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-spritecollidecollidecircle](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-spritecollidecollidecircle#main.py)</kbd>

  [image]

  ```py
  import pygame

  pygame.init()
  window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))

  sprite1 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
  sprite1.image = pygame.Surface((80, 80), pygame.SRCALPHA)
  pygame.draw.circle(sprite1.image, (255, 0, 0), (40, 40), 40)
  sprite1.rect = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(80, 80)
  sprite1.radius = 40
  sprite2 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
  sprite2.image = pygame.Surface((80, 89), pygame.SRCALPHA)
  pygame.draw.circle(sprite2.image, (0, 255, 0), (40, 40), 40)
  sprite2.rect = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(80, 80)
  sprite2.radius = 40 

  all_group = pygame.sprite.Group([sprite2, sprite1])
  test_group = pygame.sprite.Group(sprite2)

  run = True
  while run:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              run = False

      sprite1.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1, test_group, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

      window.fill(0)
      all_group.draw(window)
      for s in collide:
          pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), s.rect.center, s.rect.width // 2, 5)
      pygame.display.flip()

  pygame.quit()
  exit()
  ```

---

What does this all mean for your code?

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the centre of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword arguments are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a list of the keyword arguments).
See *[Why is my collision test always returning 'true' and why is the position of the rectangle of the image always wrong (0, 0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730329/pygame-collide-rect-function-always-returning-true/57730378#57730378)

You do not need the `x` and `y` attributes of `Sprite` and `Bullet` at all. Use the position of the `rect` attribute instead:

```py
#Define the sprite class
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(name)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def render(self):
        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# Define the bullet class to create bullets          
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.bullet = pygame.image.load("user_bullet.BMP")
        self.rect = self.bullet.get_rect(topleft = (x + 23, y))

    def render(self):
        window.blit(self.bullet, self.rect)
```

Use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to detect collisions between instances of `Sprite` and `Bullet`.
See [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152):

```py
my_sprite = Sprite(sx, sy, name)
my_bullet = Bullet(by, by)
```

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    if my_sprite.rect.colliderect(my_bullet.rect):
        printe("hit")
```

Answer (score 14):

From what I understand of pygame you just need to check if the two rectangles overlap using the [`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) method. One way to do it is to have a method in your `Bullet` class that checks for collisions:

```
def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
    return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)
```

Then you can call it like:

```
sprite = Sprite(10, 10, 'my_sprite')
bullet = Bullet(20, 10)
if bullet.is_collided_with(sprite):
    print('collision!')
    bullet.kill()
    sprite.kill()
```

Comment: Note that if the speed of bullet relative to the target is more than target's width per tick, the bullet can just 'teleport' to the other side of the target without hitting. If this might be the case, you might need to check against a rectangle that represents the trajectory of the bullet from the previous frame to the current frame, not just the bullet itself.

Answer (score 6):

There is a very simple method for what you are trying to do using built in methods.

here is an example.

```
import pygame
import sys

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.center = pos

def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 50
    bg = [255, 255, 255]
    size =[200, 200]


    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    player = Sprite([40, 50])
    player.move = [pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN]
    player.vx = 5
    player.vy = 5


    wall = Sprite([100, 60])

    wall_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    wall_group.add(wall)

    player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_group.add(player)

    # I added loop for a better exit from the game
    loop = 1
    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                loop = 0

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for i in range(2):
            if key[player.move[i]]:
                player.rect.x += player.vx * [-1, 1][i]

        for i in range(2):
            if key[player.move[2:4][i]]:
                player.rect.y += player.vy * [-1, 1][i]

        screen.fill(bg)

        # first parameter takes a single sprite
        # second parameter takes sprite groups
        # third parameter is a do kill command if true
        # all group objects colliding with the first parameter object will be
        # destroyed. The first parameter could be bullets and the second one
        # targets although the bullet is not destroyed but can be done with
        # simple trick bellow
        hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, wall_group, True)

        if hit:
            # if collision is detected call a function in your case destroy
            # bullet
            player.image.fill((255, 255, 255))

        player_group.draw(screen)
        wall_group.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

    pygame.quit()
    # sys.exit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a group for the bullets, and then add the bullets to the group.

What I would do is this:
In the class for the player:

```
def collideWithBullet(self):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, 'groupName'):
        print("CollideWithBullet!!")
        return True
```

And in the main loop somewhere:

```
def run(self):
    if self.player.collideWithBullet():
         print("Game Over")
```

Hopefully that works for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Sprite class, try adding a `self.mask` attribute with
`self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)`
and a `collide_mask` function inside of the Sprite class with this code:

```py
    def collide_mask(self, mask):
        collided = False
        mask_outline = mask.outline()
        self.mask_outline = self.mask.outline()
        for point in range(len(mask_outline)):
            mask_outline[point] = list(mask_outline[point])
            mask_outline[point][0] += bullet.x
            mask_outline[point][1] += bullet.y
        for point in range(len(self.mask_outline)):
            self.mask_outline[point] = list(mask_outline[point])
            self.mask_outline[point][0] += self.x
            self.mask_outline[point][1] += self.y
        for point in mask_outline:
            for self_mask_point in self.mask_outline:
                if point = self_mask_point:
                    collided = True
        return collided
```