# Why is my collision test always returning 'true' and why is the position of the rectangle of the image always wrong (0, 0)?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, pygame-surface

My collide_rect function isn't working properly. It always returns True, when it's not suppose to. I have tried looking on the internet but nothing is working for me. I think the collide rect somehow did not use the actual coordinates for the two sprites. Can anyone help with this?

```
import pygame
import pygame.sprite
import sys


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("test_collision")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = 280
        self.y = 475
        self.col = False
    def update(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def test_collisions(self,sprite):
        self.col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self,sprite)
class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = 1000
        self.y = 483
        self.image = pygame.image.load("obstacle.png")
        self.time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def change_x(self):
        self.time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.x = -(self.time/5) + 800
    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))


obstacle = Obstacle()
ball = Ball()      
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    ball.update()
    obstacle.change_x()
    obstacle.update()
    ball.test_collisions(obstacle)
    if ball.col:
        print("colided")
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(1000)


pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

P.S This is my first post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The *Surface* is placed at a position on the display with the `blit` function.

You've to set the location of the rectangle, either by a keyword argument, e.g:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))
```

or an assignment to a virtual attribute (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)), e.g:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
```

---

It is absolutely unnecessary to add some extra attributes `self.x` and `self.y`. Use the location of the rectangle instead. e.g:

```py
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (280, 475))
        self.col = False
    def update(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    def test_collisions(self,sprite):
        self.col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self,sprite)

class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("obstacle.png")
        self.time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (1000, 483))
    def change_x(self):
        self.time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.rect.x = -(self.time/5) + 800
    def update(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

---

Further note, that you can get rid of the methods `Ball.update()` respectively `Obstacle.update()` (you can delete them), if you use a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and call [`.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw), which uses the `.image` and `.rect` properties of the contained sprites, to draw them. e.g.:

```py
obstacle = Obstacle()
ball = Ball()      
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([obstacle, ball])

while not crashed:

    # [...]
  
    gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    
    all_sprites.draw(gameDisplay)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(1000)
```