# Pygame Surface Positioning

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

As I understood pygame drawing method, the 2nd argument of the [blit function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) (`screen.blit(surface, (0,0))`) tells pygame where to draw the given surface (like an offset to start drawing from, or rather a placement of the surface on the screen). Although, from recent experimenting, it seems that pygame surfaces placements are fixed, and that `(0,0)` is used to crop the surface before pygame blit it to the screen, for efficiency purposes.

Are surfaces placement really fixed (is my latter observation correct)? and if so, is there another way to conveniently move an already drawn surface to another position on the screen? Or should i implement my own way of moving complex "drawable" objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object has no position, it has a size only. Note, the location of the `Rect` object which is returned by [`pygame.Surface.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) is always (0, 0).
When you [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) a `Surface` on another `Surface`, then each pixel is copied and placed at the corresponding position of the destination `Surface`. Thus always a position has to be specified, when a `Surface` is `blit` on a destination `Surface`.

See also [Why is my collision test always returning 'true' and why is the position of the rectangle of the image always wrong (0, 0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730329/why-is-my-collision-test-always-returning-true-and-why-is-the-position-of-the)

---

> [...]  if so, is there another way to conveniently move an already drawn surface to another position [...]

You have a basic misunderstanding. A `Surface` cannot be "moved". A `Surface` is copied on the `Surface` object which is associated to the game window.
A `Surface` appears to be moving, because the entire scene is drawn in every frame. First the background is drawn, then the objects (Sprites, Surfaces) are drawn on top of the background and finally the display is updated (in every frame). If an object is placed at a slightly different position in every frame, then the object appears to be moving smoothly.

Comment: Excellent. So a surface is, well, a surface, and I should be able to `blit` it unto the screen in a given location. I guess I missed something in my experimenting. Thank you!