# Why are my colliders so unruly and unaccurate? And how can I improve them?

Tags: python, pygame

I am having the issue that, my colliders aren't accurate. No matter how I tweak the numbers, they wont work. The eagle, the birds collider is accurate, but the collider of the box/obstacle isn't. The rectangle I use as a collider is the same size as the image of the box, and should be centered on it, but for some reason, it isn't.

```py
import pygame as pg # imports life juice

eagleImage = pg.image.load("playerflappybirdscaled.png") # loads fucking eagle image
eagleCollider = pg.Surface.get_bounding_rect(eagleImage) # better collider

boxImage = pg.image.load("boxcollider.png") # box image go load
boxCollider = pg.Surface.get_bounding_rect(boxImage) # makes box rect

class Box(object): # makes box
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = boxImage # image of a box
        self.collider = boxCollider # collider for said box

        self.x = x # box xpos
        self.y = y # box ypos
        self.collider.center = self.x, self.y

    def checkCollision(self, rect): # checks for collision
        self.collider.center = self.x, self.y # sets collider
        colliderToCheckFor = rect # gets other collider
        collision = boxCollider.colliderect(colliderToCheckFor) # checks for collision
        if collision: # returns car crash
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))



class Bird(object): # bird go flyyyyyyyyyyy
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = eagleImage # bird go display
        self.collider = eagleCollider # bird gets collider

        self.x = 320 # bird posx
        self.y = 200 # bird posy

    def key_handler(self, moveDist, direction): # manhandles keys
        key = pg.key.get_pressed() # gets manhandled keys
        dist = 2 # distance in FREEDOM UNITS jk

        if key[pg.K_UP]: # key go up
            self.y -= dist
        elif key[pg.K_SPACE]: # key go up
            self.y -= dist
        elif key[pg.K_w]: # key go up
            self.y -= dist
        elif key[pg.K_a]: # key go left
            self.x -= dist

        if moveDist == 0: # checks if distance moved is wanted
            return # if not returns
        else:
            if direction == "y": # checks direction wanted
                self.y += moveDist # does shit
            elif direction == "x":
                self.x += moveDist

    def draw(self, surface): # toddler draws image
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.collider.center = self.x, self.y 

pg.init() # starts pygame
s = pg.display.set_mode((640, 400)) # sets screen

box = Box(320, 50)
bird = Bird() # biiiiiird
clock = pg.time.Clock() # clock for fps and shit

running = True # if runs
while running: # when runs
    event = pg.event.poll() # get event
    if event.type == pg.QUIT: # if not run go quit
        pg.quit()
        running = False
        break

    bird.key_handler(1, "y") # bird mauls keys

    s.fill((255, 0, 0)) # give screen color

    box.draw(s)

    bird.draw(s) # take drawing from toddler

    pg.display.update() # put drawing on display

    if box.checkCollision(eagleCollider) == True:
        running = False
        pg.quit()

    clock.tick(60) # tick tack
```

So as I have said, I have tried tweaking every number, and I see no reason why the colliders wouldn't be accurate.

Edit to highlight the difference between questions this one has been associated with. I have actually followed and implemented answers from one of these questions to the best of my ability, and as far as I can tell, I have followed what was answered there.

Answer (score 0):

See [Why is my collision test always returning 'true' and why is the position of the rectangle of the image always wrong (0, 0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730329/why-is-my-collision-test-always-returning-true-and-why-is-the-position-of-the).

The instruction `surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))` draws `self.image` at the **`topleft`** position (`self.x`, `self.y`):

```py
class Box(object): # makes box
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = boxImage # image of a box
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        self.collider = self.image.get_bounding_rect()
        self.collider.x += x
        self.collider.y += y

    def checkCollision(self, rect): # checks for collision
        collision = self.collider.colliderect(rect)
        return collision

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```