# Is there a class in pygame to represent a non-AABB polygon?

Tags: python, pygame, polygon, draw, collision

I am making a game in python with pygame, and I am wondering if there is any class (with collisions) in pygame that supports non-AABB polygons. I know there is the `pygame.draw.polygon` function, but that takes a list of points instead of a rect like `pygame.draw.rect`.

Is there any way to do this in pygame?

If not, are there any pygame-compatible libraries that could do this?

If there are no libraries, how could I implement it?

Comment: Thanks, that seems great! Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pygame.draw`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) module does not generate objects. It just draws something on a *Surface*. You cannot use this for collision detection. I think you're confusing [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and the `pygame.draw` module.
The collision detection in pygame is based on rectangles or circles. See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907).
Another option is to use [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) objects, which you can use to detect overlapping shapes and sprites. See [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039)