# pygame mask overlapping shapes of different color?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

how is it possible to create masks of different color shapes on a surface and check for overlap collision?

suppose I have a green circle and a red polygon on a surface. I want to know when they end up colliding while moving.

I tried something like this:

```py
circle_color = (0,255,0)
polygon_color = (255,0,0)

circle_mask = pygame.mask.from_threshold(SURFACE, circle_color)
polygon_mask = pygame.mask.from_threshold(SURFACE, polygon_color)

if circle_mask.overlap(polygon_mask, offset=(0,0)):
   print("collision")
```

but collision doesn't get detected, I guess I'm missing something. what's a way to do this?

EDIT: I'm trying to get masks of shapes created with pygame.draw() function and not sprites or assets. Also I want to get pixel perfect collision because my polygons are not rectangles

Comment: what means `doesn't work`? Do you get error message? Then show FULL error message in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Do you get wrong values? Then show it in question. We can't run your code, we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: I think you use it in wrong way. Usually you have two images (two moving objects/players) and you create masks for those image - and later you check if they have similar position and later you check they mask to make sure they overlap. But it seems you use the same `SURFACE` and probably expect to create two masks from one surface. Maybe you should display masks to see what you really get. Maybe one color crops other color and your masks don't overlap.

Comment: @furas no error messages, simply collision doesn't get detected. I would not have omitted them if they were present. (edited post)

Comment: You chose not to offer a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. You haven't shown us the contents of those two masks. It's unclear what process you thought internet strangers would use to arrive at a useful solution to the stated problem.

Comment: @J_H Maybe I'm still not getting how these damn masks are supposed to work, tbh

Comment: your code suggest that you use it in an unprecedented way. You use mask to find objects on screen (full window) and you check if masks overlap. But normally you create mask only once - at start. You get image of player (without background) and you create its mask. Later you use standard functions to check collision with other objects - using `rectangles` - and when rectangles overlap then you use `mask` (which have the same size as rectangles) to check if details overlaps.

Comment: you should rather draw circle on small surface, and make mask from this surface. Next draw polygon on another small surface, and make mask from this surface, Later you should move circle and polygon and use `Rect()` to check collision between `circle's rect` and `polygon's rect` and when they overlap then check collisions between `circle's mask` and `polygon's mask`. You should create mask from full screen.

Comment: Your solution does not work because the masks of 2 objects drawn on the screen no longer overlap. If you draw the second object over the first one, part of the first object is covered and therefore no longer contained in the mask.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not work because the masks of 2 objects drawn on the screen no longer overlap. If you draw the second object over the first one, part of the first object is covered and therefore no longer contained in the mask.
To make your solution work you have to generate the masks directly after drawing the object groups:

1. draw all objects with `circle_color`
2. `circle_mask = pygame.mask.from_threshold(SURFACE, circle_color)`
3. draw all objects with `polygon_color` (on top of objects with `circle_color`)
4. `polygon_mask = pygame.mask.from_threshold(SURFACE, polygon_color)`
5. `if circle_mask.overlap(polygon_mask, offset=(0,0)):`

However, this is not the way collision detection should be implemented. Generating a mask of the entire screen twice in each frame and then comparing them will not perform well. An algorithm where you first limit the possible collisions of objects by rectangle collision detection and then make a collision test of the remaining objects based on the mask will perform best.
Draw the objects on small `pygame.Surfces` objects and get the masks from them.   Then you can use the standard mask collision detection like e.g. here [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039).