# What is Pygame.Rect() is used for in a program?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, pygame, pygame2

Can anyone tell me the use of `Pygame.Rect`. I am creating a simple program to draw and display rectangle in screen and check for collision with screen. I saw a video on youtube where the Youtuber uses the following code:

```py
moving_rect=pygame.Rect(300,300,100,100)
```

Now I don't know what is `Pygame.Rect` is used for and what the above line of code actually does.

Answer (score 1):

A [`pygame.Rec`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) describes a rectangular area. It can be use to define the bounding box of an object. This can be  useful for a collision test. See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907).

Actually it is used to define the location of a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) object.
Notice that a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object has no position. It only contains the pixel information. However, a *Rect* and a *Surface* together define the position of an image (Sprite) in the window.