# How to add a point system and scoreboard to a game?

Tags: python, pygame

How do I add some sort of collision detection between the rectangle and the circles? and how do I make it to where every time a circle is collided with, it gives me 1 point? I'm trying to get familiar with coding and Python, I know I probably shouldn't be doing all of this when I'm relatively new and should be learning actual Python instead, but I'm stuck on this and it's just bugging me.

```
import pygame
import random


pygame.init()
y = 0
x = 0
point = 0
is_blue = True
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
food_pos = random.randint(1, 400)

food_list = []
time_interval = 3000
next_food_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            is_blue = not is_blue

    pygame.display.set_caption("Collect the balls to win!")

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 3
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 3
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 3
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 3

    if x <= -1:
        x = 0
    if x >= 471:
        x = 470
    if y <= -1:
        y = 0
    if y >= 471:
        y = 470

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > next_food_time and len(food_list) < 10:
        next_food_time += time_interval
        food_list.append((random.randint(1, 400), random.randint(1, 400)))

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if is_blue:
        color = (0, 128, 255)
    else:
        color = (255, 100, 0)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 30))
    for food_pos in food_list:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, food_pos, 5)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(144)
```

Answer (score 2):

See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907)

Create [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects for the player and the food. Use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to detect collision between the player and the food. If a collision is detected, remove the food from the list and increase the points:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    player_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 30)
    for food_pos in food_list[:]:
        food_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10)
        food_rect.center = food_pos
        if player_rect.colliderect(food_rect):
            food_list.remove(food_pos)
            point += 1
            print(point)

    # [...]
```