# How can I get rect from a sprite group?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a spritegroup. When a member of the spritegroup has a collision, I want to know the rect's position. Here I got the error message  'Group' object has no attribute 'x'

```
class Landschaft(pygame.sprite.Sprite):       
    def __init__(self,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        self.image = image       
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()            
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(60, breite -60)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(100, hoehe - 200) 
        self.rect.center = ( self.rect.x,self.rect.y)

land = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(5):
      image = gegend[i]     
      m = Landschaft(image)        
      hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m,land,True)
        
      if hits:
          i-=1
          print(land.rect.x) 

      land.add(m)
```

Comment: Is the problem solved? Is the answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

A *Group* has no rectangle and position. Only the items in the *Group* have a `.rect` attribute.
[`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) returns a list of sprites.
Furthermore you need to pass `False` to the *doKill* argument of `spritecollide`. If the parameter is `True`, all *Sprites* that collide will be removed from the *Group*.

You have to pass `False` to *doKill*:

```py
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, land, False)
for hit_sprite in hits:        
    i-=1
    print(hit_sprite.rect.x)
```

---

Also see [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907)