# No error but sprite has completely disappeared after adding collision in the x-axis

Tags: python, pygame

I can't find a way to get it back, I even made it super big but it still wasn't there, none of the image loading or drawing on to screen was touched when coding the collision so I'm just really confused. Can someone please have a look and tell me what's happening?

full code here:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

size = width, height = 1000, 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
ScreenRect = screen.get_rect()
pygame.display.set_caption("Snail Platformer")

#Game variables
TileSize = 50



#load background
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.png')

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.SnailRight = []
        self.SnailLeft = []
        self.index = 0
        self.counter = 0

        for num in range(1, 3):
            right = pygame.image.load(f'right{num}.png')
            right = pygame.transform.scale(right, (128, 128))
            left = pygame.transform.flip(right, True, False)
            self.SnailRight.append(right)
            self.SnailLeft.append(left)
        self.image = self.SnailRight[self.index]      
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = self.image.get_width
        self.height = self.image.get_height
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jump = False
        self.direct = 0

    def draw(self):

        x1 = 0
        y1 = 0
        Anim = 10

        #move snail

        Keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if Keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x1 -= 2
            self.counter += 1
            self.direct = -1

        if Keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x1 += 2
            self.counter += 1
            self.direct = 1


        if Keys[pygame.K_LEFT] == False and Keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False:
            self.counter = 0
            self.index = 0
            if self.direct == 1:
                self.image = self.SnailRight[self.index]
            if self.direct == -1:
                self.image = self.SnailLeft[self.index]

        if Keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or Keys[pygame.K_UP] and self.jump == False:
            self.vel_y = -15
            self.jump = True
        if Keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or Keys[pygame.K_UP] == False:
            self.jump = False        


        #Animation
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter > Anim:
            self.counter = 0
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.SnailRight):
               self.index = 0
            if self.direct == 1:
                self.image = self.SnailRight[self.index]
            if self.direct == -1:
                self.image = self.SnailLeft[self.index]
            
        

        #Gravity
        self.vel_y += 1
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y = 10
        y1 += self.vel_y


        #Collision Detection
        for tile in world.TileList:
            if tile[1].colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.rect.x + x1, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height)):
                x1 = 0
                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    y1 = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                if self.vel_y >= 0:
                    y1 = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
            


 
        self.rect.x += x1
        self.rect.y += y1

        if self.rect.bottom > height:
            self.rect.bottom = height
            y1 = 0

        

        #draw snail
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect, 2)



class World():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.TileList = []

        #load platforms images
        dirt = pygame.image.load('dirt.png')
        grass = pygame.image.load('grass.png')

        rowCount = 0
        for row in data:
            columnCount = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt, (TileSize, TileSize))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = columnCount * TileSize
                    img_rect.y = rowCount * TileSize
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.TileList.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(grass, (TileSize, TileSize))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = columnCount * TileSize
                    img_rect.y = rowCount * TileSize
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.TileList.append(tile)
                columnCount += 1
            rowCount += 1

    def draw(self):
        for tile in self.TileList:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), tile[1], 2)

WorldData = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1], 
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],  
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

Snail = Player(25, height - 130) 
world = World(WorldData)


#main loop
run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(60)

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    world.draw()

    Snail.draw()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The first part of this answer was already given in the comments of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490625/typeerror-argument-must-be-rect-style-object-when-using-colliderect-function/70490670#70490670).)

It doesn't quite disappear: it spawns within the wall and shoots upwards.
A potential fix would be to make your player smaller and move it a bit so that it doesn't spawn within the wall, and also to fix your collision detection section as I've suggested in your other question.

To summarise:
Edit your collision detection into this:

```
# Collision Detection
    for tile in world.TileList:
        if tile[1].colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.rect.x + x1, self.rect.y, self.rect.width, self.rect.height)):
            x1 = 0
        if tile[1].colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + y1, self.rect.width, self.rect.height)):
            y1 = 0
            if self.vel_y < 0:
                y1 = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
            if self.vel_y >= 0:
                y1 = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
```

Within your constructor for Player, modify this line:
`right = pygame.transform.scale(right, (128, 128))`
to this:
`right = pygame.transform.scale(right, (32, 32))`

Just above your main loop, modify this line:
`Snail = Player(25, height - 130)`
to this:
`Snail = Player(50, height - 130)`

Once you verify that this works, you can play around with the actual values and adjust them to your liking. All we've done here is make the player smaller, move it out of the wall and, indeed, modify the collision detection.

Also note that you forgot the `rect` in `self.width` and `self.height` again. :)

Comment: Ahh thank you so much I didn't expect to have this much trouble when copying from a tutorial which showed it working for them but you managed to fix everything so thank you, I can finally go to bed XD

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.Surface.get_width`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_width) and [`pygame.Surface.get_height`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height) are methods. You have to use the parentheses (`()`), to call a method.

<s>`self.width = self.image.get_width`</s>
<s>`self.height = self.image.get_height`</s>

```py
self.width = self.image.get_width()
self.height = self.image.get_height()
```

Anyway, you don't need the `width` and `height` attribute at all. The width and height is stored in the `rect` attribute:

```py
if tile[1].colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.rect.x + x1, self.rect.y, self.rect.width, self.rect.height)):
    # [...]
```

You can also use the [`pygame.Rect.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) method. This method returns a new and moved rectnagle:

```py
if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.move(x1, 0)):
    # [...]
```

To make your code work, you have to separate the collision detection along for the x-axis and y-axis:

```py
class Player():
    # [...]
  
    def draw(self):
        # [...]

        for tile in world.TileList:
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.move(x1, 0)):
                if x1 > 0:
                    self.rect.right = tile[1].left
                elif x1 < 0:
                    self.rect.left = tile[1].right
                x1 = 0
                break

        for tile in world.TileList:
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.move(x1, y1)):
                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    y1 = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                if self.vel_y >= 0:
                    y1 = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom

        self.rect.x += x1
        self.rect.y += y1

        # [...]
```

And you have to find a starting position for the player that does not collide with the boundaries of the grid. e.g:

`Snail = Player(25, height - 130)`

```py
Snail = Player(50, height - 130)
```

or

```py
Snail = Player(width // 2, height // 2)
```