# How do I use sprite collisions correctly here?

Tags: python, pygame

```
list_zombies = pygame.sprite.Group()
walls = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, list_zombies)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = zombie_speed
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Zombie.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos1 = self.x
        self.pos2 = self.y

    def update(self):
        self.y += zombie_speed

    def main(self, display):
        self.update()
        display.blit(zombie_image_copy, (self.x, self.y))

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, walls)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.image = wall_image.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def main(display):

        display.blit(wall_image, (-100, 950))

main loop:


for zombie in list_zombies:
        zombie.rect.topleft = (zombie.x, zombie.y)

        if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(list_zombies, walls, 0, 0, collided= None):
            zombie.kill()
```

These are my classes and i want to kill the zombie if it hits the wall. I have used groupcollide since spritecollide wouldn't work and I would get the error that Wall doesn't have the attribute rect. Somehow it is not working but also not giving me an error. Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907) and read the documentation! [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

The `rect` attribute is also used for collision detection functions like [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). You don't need the `.x` and `.y` attributes at all. If you use the `.rect` attribute (`.rect.x` and `.rect.y`) insterad, collision detection works immediately.

If you want to store sprite positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate attributes. Synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object when the position of the object is changed in the `update` method:

```py
def update(self):
    
    self.x = # change
    self.y = # change

    self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```