# collisions in python pygame between a randomly spawned Object an player by hitboxes

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

I code for the first time with pygame and no one can help me ecause all may friends code wit javascript
I wrote those lines of Code and I want to do something when Food and player collide. This is my code and I want to do it the easiest way:

```
import pygame
import os
import random

pygame.init()
win_height = 400
win_width = 800
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))


class Hero:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Walk
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.velx = 10
        self.vely = 6
        self.face_right = True
        self.face_left = False
        self.stepIndex = 0
        self.hitboxPlayer = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 50, 112.5)
        # Jump
        self.jump = False

    def draw(self, win):
        self.hitboxPlayer = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 50, 112.5)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), self.hitboxPlayer, 1)
        if self.stepIndex >= 3:
            self.stepIndex = 0
        if self.face_left:
            win.blit(left[self.stepIndex], (self.x, self.y))
            self.stepIndex += 1
        if self.face_right:
            win.blit(right[self.stepIndex], (self.x, self.y))
            self.stepIndex += 1


    def jump_motion(self, userInput):
        if userInput[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jump is False:
            self.jump = True
        if self.jump:
            self.y -= self.vely * 4
            self.vely -= 1
        if self.vely < -6:
            self.jump = False
            self.vely = 6

    def direction(self):
        if self.face_right:
            return 1
        if self.face_left:
            return -1


class Food:
    def __init__(self, lx, hx):
        self.y = 0
        self.speed = 5
        self.highestx = win_width
        self.x = random.randint(0,self.highestx)
        self.sprite = str(1)
        self.FoodCount = []
        self.hitboxFood = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 50, 50)
       

    def draw(self):
        self.hitboxFood = pygame.Rect(self.x + 15, self.y + 15, 50, 50)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), self.hitboxFood, 1)
        win.blit(food, (self.x,self.y))
        self.sprite = win.blit(food, (self.x,self.y))
        if self.y == win_height-200:
            print("Ground ")
        if snacks.hitboxFood.colliderect(player.hitboxPlayer) :
            print("hit")

        
    def move(self):
        self.y += self.speed


def draw_game():
    global tower_health, speed
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(background, (0, 0))
    
    player.draw(win)

    for snack in snacks.FoodCount:
        snack.draw()
        snack.move()
                

    pygame.time.delay(30)
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)

snacks = Food(0, win_width)
player = Hero(250, 290)

run = True
while run:

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            snacks.spawn()

    userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player.move_hero(userInput)
    player.jump_motion(userInput)

    draw_game()
```

and I really don't know how to do this... I tried so much
tanks for helping!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried searching on Google `pygame detect collision`. I did and this is what I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame), I hope this does help you.

Spending time searching on Google is the first thing you should think of when learning to code or using a new module.