# implementing collision correctly for rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to experiment with pygame and I am creating a simple prototype game.

I need some help with collision for a player rect and a "food" rect.
I am trying to make a simple game that has a player and a food object. the food object's location is randomized when the game starts

```py
class Food(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rand_x = random.randint(0, width)
        self.rand_y = random.randint(0, height)
        self.food = pg.Rect(self.rand_x,
                            self.rand_y,
                            15, 15)
    ...
```

this food class contains a function that handles the collision of the player and food, if the player collides with the food, the location of the food changes again

```py
    def playerCollision(self):
        if self.sprite.colliderect(self.food) or self.food.colliderect(self.sprite):
            self.food.x = self.rand_x
            self.food.y = self.rand_y
```

Here's my player class

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite = pg.Rect(x, y, 50, 50)

    def handle_keys(self):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(0, -velocity)
        elif keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(-velocity, 0)
        elif keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(0, velocity)
        elif keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(velocity, 0)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pg.draw.rect(surface, spriteColors[0], self.sprite)
```

and heres the full food class

```py
class Food(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rand_x = random.randint(0, width)
        self.rand_y = random.randint(0, height)
        self.food = pg.Rect(self.rand_x,
                            self.rand_y,
                            15, 15)

    def randomize_pos(self):  # debugger function to test randomized food locations
        self.food.x = random.randint(0, width)
        self.food.y = random.randint(0, height)
        self.drawFood(screen)

    def playerCollision(self):
        if self.sprite.colliderect(self.food) or self.food.colliderect(self.sprite):
            self.food.x = self.rand_x
            self.food.y = self.rand_y

    def drawFood(self, surface):
        pg.draw.rect(surface, spriteColors[1], self.food)
```

I've looked everywhere for solutions and implementing solutions into my code but none work.

Heres the full code if you all need it

```py
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *
import sys, random

pg.init()

# Setup and screen properties
pg.display.set_caption("prototype \u2014 game")
width, height = (800, 600)
screen = pg.display.set_mode([width, height])
spriteColors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]  # Red, Green, Blue

x = 25
y = 25
velocity = 5

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite = pg.Rect(x, y, 50, 50)

    def handle_keys(self):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(0, -velocity)
        elif keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(-velocity, 0)
        elif keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(0, velocity)
        elif keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.sprite.move_ip(velocity, 0)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pg.draw.rect(surface, spriteColors[0], self.sprite)

class Food(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rand_x = random.randint(0, width)
        self.rand_y = random.randint(0, height)
        self.food = pg.Rect(self.rand_x,
                            self.rand_y,
                            15, 15)

    def randomize_pos(self):  # debugger function to test randomized food locations
        self.food.x = random.randint(0, width)
        self.food.y = random.randint(0, height)
        self.drawFood(screen)

    def playerCollision(self):
        if self.sprite.colliderect(self.food) or self.food.colliderect(self.sprite):
            self.food.x = self.rand_x
            self.food.y = self.rand_y

    def drawFood(self, surface):
        pg.draw.rect(surface, spriteColors[1], self.food)


# Initialize Player and Food Object
player = Player()
food = Food()
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# Game Loop
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    player.handle_keys()
    player.draw(screen)
    food.drawFood(screen)
    food.playerCollision()
    pg.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907).
In your particular code, `player` and `food` are different objects. `player.sprite` is not the same as `food.sprite`. The inheritance from `Player` in `Food` is useless, remove it. You must pass the `player` object to the `playerCollision`  method of the `food` object:

```py
class Food():
    def __init__(self):
        self.food = pg.Rect(0, 0, 15, 15)
        self.randomize_pos()

    def randomize_pos(self):
        self.food.x = random.randint(0, width)
        self.food.y = random.randint(0, height)

    def playerCollision(self, player):
        if player.sprite.colliderect(self.food):
            self.randomize_pos()

    def drawFood(self, surface):
        pg.draw.rect(surface, spriteColors[1], self.food)
```

```py
# Initialize Player and Food Object
player = Player()
food = Food()
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# Game Loop
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    player.handle_keys()
    player.draw(screen)
    food.drawFood(screen)
    food.playerCollision(player)     # <-- detect collision between food and player 
    pg.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: that seemed to work just perfectly, I just imagined I would use inheritance to try to make it work but I was wrong, thanks for your help