# pygame detecting if drawn circle sprite is clicked failing

Tags: python, pygame, position, mouseevent

I am working on a small game where if you click a circle it makes a pop sound and goes back to the bottom my problem is when I switched to using a class and sprite to allow multiple circles it no longer will detect if one is clicked what am I doing wrong?

```
class Bubble(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):

        self.radius = random.randint(50,100)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.radius/2,self.radius/2])
        self.image.fill(blue)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(bPath+"Images\\Bubble.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.bx = random.randint(70, 1466)
        self.x = self.bx
        self.y = 930
        self.way = 0
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def move(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(tv,blue,(self.x,self.y),self.radius)
        
        self.y -= 2

        if self.x == self.bx+20:
            self.way = 1
        elif self.x == self.bx-20:
            self.way = 0
        else:
            pass

        if self.way == 0:
            self.x += 1
        else:
            self.x -= 1

        if self.y <= 0:
            self.bx = random.randint(70, 1466)
            self.x = self.bx
            self.y = 930
            self.radius=random.randint(50,100)
        else:
            pass

bubbleList = []

nBubble = 0
while True:
    tv.fill(white)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for b in bubbleList:
                if b.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    print("hi")
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    if pygame.time.get_ticks() > nBubble:
        nBubble += 5000

        if len(bubbleList) < 10:
            bubbleList.append(Bubble())
        else:
            pass
        
    for b in bubbleList:
        b.move()
    
    pygame.display.update()
    FramePerSec.tick(fps)
```

I have looked at a couple other similar posts on here and have implemented them as you can probably see. It throws no errors on my computer it just does nothing when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are `self.x` and `self.y` for? You don't need these attributes. You have `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`. The collision detection depends on the position stored in the `rect` attribute.

> ```py
> if b.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
> ```

However, `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` do not magically change when you change `self.x` and `self.y`. The position stored in the `rect` attribute is not tied to `self.x` and `self.y`. Get rid of `self.x` and `self.y`:

```py
class Bubble(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self):

       self.radius = random.randint(50,100)
       self.image = pygame.Surface([self.radius/2,self.radius/2])
       self.image.fill(blue)
       self.image = pygame.image.load(bPath+"Images\\Bubble.png")
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.bx = random.randint(70, 1466)
       self.way = 0
       self.rect.x = self.bx
       self.rect.y = 930

   def move(self):
       pygame.draw.circle(tv, blue, self.rect.center, self.radius)
       
       self.rect.y -= 2
       if self.rect.x == self.bx+20:
           self.way = 1
       elif self.rect.x == self.bx-20:
           self.way = 0
       else:
           pass

       if self.way == 0:
           self.rect.x += 1
       else:
           self.rect.x -= 1

       if self.rect.y <= 0:
           self.bx = random.randint(70, 1466)
           self.rect.x = self.bx
           self.rect.y = 930
           self.radius=random.randint(50,100)
       else:
           pass
```

See also [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907).

Comment: When I click it does not register the current position.  If I click below the circle it registers still like it is grabbing a previous position.

Comment: @LostSilverCoin `pygame.draw.circle(tv, blue, self.rect.center, self.radius)` - `self.rect.center` instead of `self.rect.topleft`