# I need help to check if my sprite, evil cookie, is colliding with the border rectangle. I've done this but it results in an error

Tags: python, pygame

Exact error message is below, including the code associated.

Hello everyone. I am trying to make something that checks if an evil cookie has collided with the border rectangle, so that I can use this to make the evil cookies bounce from top to bottom. I'm not sure how to and usually end up with this error:

> ```
>  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Cookie Cafe\Cookie Cafe\cookie_cafe_4.py", line 215, in <module>
>    collisioncookie(evil)
>  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Cookie Cafe\Cookie Cafe\cookie_cafe_4.py", line 78, in collisioncookie
>    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(item,border_bottom, False):
>  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1706, in spritecollide
>    return [
>  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1709, in <listcomp>
>    if default_sprite_collide_func(group_sprite.rect)
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rect'
> ```

```
# the_cookie_cafe.py

# Part four  - collisions

import pygame,sys
import random
cookie_collided = False
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.sprites = []
        self.is_animating = False
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("ghostanim1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("ghostanim2.png").convert_alpha())
    
        self.csprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.csprite]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]
        
    def update(self):
        if self.is_animating == True:
            self.csprite += 0.05

            if int(self.csprite) >= len(self.sprites):
                self.csprite = 0
                self.is_animating = False
                # Bug fixing - list cannot go above 0 so image won't lead to error
            self.image = self.sprites[int(self.csprite)]

    def animate(self):
        self.is_animating = True

    def move(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.rect.x-player_speed_x, self.rect.y-player_speed_y)
        self.rect.move_ip(-player_speed_x, -player_speed_y)

class EvilCookie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path,pos_x,pos_y):
        global rect
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(picture_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),self)
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]

    def update(self):
        if cookie_collided == False:     
            self.rect.y += 1
        else:
            pass

    def topcollide(self):
        if cookie_collided == True:  
            self.rect.y -= 2
        else:
            pass
        
    def bottomcollide(self):
        if cookie_collided == True:  
            self.rect.y += 2
        else:
            pass
        
class EdibleCookie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(picture_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width/2,screen_height/2))
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]

def checkcollision(item):
    item.rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())

def collisioncookie(item):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(item,border_bottom, False):
        print("collide bottom")
        
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        
# Main window - defines window definitons and the screen itself, the "surface"
screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 960
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Cookie Cafe') # Sets window title

# Images - loads images with pixel accuracy (convert_alpha)
background = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert_alpha()
bigenemy = pygame.image.load("enemybig.png").convert_alpha()
smallenemy = pygame.image.load("enemysmall.png").convert_alpha()
goodenemy = pygame.image.load("goodcookie.png").convert_alpha()

# Rectangles - Creates rectangles which defines where images/characters can be 
cookerrect = pygame.Rect(1000, 550, 200, 200)
backgroundrect = background.get_rect()
backgroundrect.center = (screen_width/2, screen_height/2)

# Sprite group: MOVING SPRITES
moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(300,700)
moving_sprites.add(player)

# Sprite group: Edible Cookies
goodcookie = EdibleCookie("goodcookie.png",random.randrange(600,800),random.randrange(0,800))
goodcookie_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
goodcookie_group.add(goodcookie)

# Sprite group: Evil Cookies
evil = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil2 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil3 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil4 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil5 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil6 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil7 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil8 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil9 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil10 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil11 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil12 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil13 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil14 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil15 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil16 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil17 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil18 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil19 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil20 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil21 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))

evil_cookies = pygame.sprite.Group()
evil_cookies.add(evil,evil2,evil3,evil4,evil5,evil6,evil7,evil8,evil9,evil10,evil11,evil12,evil13,evil14,evil15,evil16,evil17,evil18,evil19,evil20,evil21)

# Speed and movement control
player_speed_x = 0
player_speed_y = 0
screen.blit(background,backgroundrect) # Prints images 

origin_x = 300
origin_y = 700

# Border
border_top = pygame.Rect(0,0,1500,10)
border_bottom = (0,955,1500,10)

# Music
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

# Loop
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        player.move(int(origin_x),int(origin_y))
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Checking inputs, here, QUIT is checked (leave game)
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed_y -= 1
                origin_y -= 1
                player.animate()
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed_y += 1
                origin_y += 1
                player.animate()
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_speed_x -= 1
                origin_x -= 1
                player.animate()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_speed_x += 1
                origin_x += 1
                player.animate()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed_y += 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed_y -= 1
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_speed_x += 1
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_speed_x -= 1
    
    player.move(origin_x,origin_y)
    screen.blit(background,backgroundrect)
    moving_sprites.draw(screen)
    moving_sprites.update()
    evil_cookies.draw(screen)
    evil_cookies.update()
    goodcookie_group.draw(screen)
    goodcookie_group.update()
    checkcollision(player)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),border_top)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),border_bottom)
    
    badhit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,evil_cookies, False)
    if badhit:
        print("Hit Evil Cookie")
        
    goodhit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,goodcookie_group, False)
    if goodhit:
        print("Hit GoodCookie")
        
    collisioncookie(evil)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60) # Keeps FPS at 60 to prevent lag or un-playable game
```

Answer (score 2):

See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907). The 2nd argument of [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) needs to be a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). However, `border_bottom` is a rectangle. Use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) instead of `pygame.sprite.spritecollide`:

```py
def collisioncookie(item):
    if item.rect.colliderect(border_bottom):
        print("collide bottom")
```