# How do I find the rect of an item in a list?

Tags: python, list, class, pygame, rect

In pygame, I am making a bootleg flappy bird and I am using classes for the pipes. I was wondering if there is a way to get the rect of a pipe in the list of pipes.
I want to check for collisions between the bird and the pipe using the .colliderect() method. Here's the code to see what you are working with.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
music = pygame.mixer.music.load("audio/music.mp3")
flap = pygame.mixer.Sound("audio/flap.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.05)
flap.set_volume(0.2)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
level = 1
sw = 1080
sh = 700
bird_grav = 10
bird_jump = 200
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((sw,sh))
groundsurface = pygame.image.load("graphics/ground.png")
pipesurf = pygame.image.load("graphics/pipe.png")
groundrect = groundsurface.get_rect(midtop=(540,580))
bgoverlay = pygame.image.load("graphics/bgoverlay.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("Flap.")
index = 1
bgsurf = pygame.image.load("graphics/bg2.png")

class pipe:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = pipesurf
        self.piperect = self.img.get_rect(midbottom=(x,y))
        self.rotimg = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, 180)
        self.rotimgrect = self.rotimg.get_rect(midtop=(x, y-700))
        screen.blit(self.img, self.piperect)
        screen.blit(self.rotimg, self.rotimgrect)
x = 50
y = 350
game_over = False
pipes = []
birdsurf = pygame.image.load("graphics/bird.png")
birdrect = birdsurf.get_rect(center=(x,y))
while running:
    if level == 1:
        if not game_over:
            pipes.clear()
            clock.tick(60)
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event == pygame.QUIT:
                    break
                    exit()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(flap)
                    y -= bird_jump
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_b:
                        if index == 2:
                            index = 0
                        index += 1
                        if index == 1:
                            bgsurf = pygame.image.load("graphics/bg2.png")
                        if index == 2 or 0:
                            bgsurf = pygame.image.load("graphics/bg1.png")
            birdsurf = pygame.image.load("graphics/bird.png")
            birdrect = birdsurf.get_rect(center=(x,y))
            screen.fill((128,217,255))
            screen.blit(bgsurf, (0,0))
            screen.blit(bgoverlay, (0,0))
            pipes.append(pipe(300, 700))
            pipes.append(pipe(500, 580))
            pipes.append(pipe(700, 680))
            pipes.append(pipe(900, 630))
            if birdrect.colliderect():
                print("test")
            screen.blit(groundsurface, groundrect)
            x += 10
            y += bird_grav
            screen.blit(birdsurf, birdrect)
            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907). [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) Test for intersection of 2 rectangles. e.g.:

```py
for aPipe in pipes:
    if birdrect.colliderect(aPipe.piperect):
        print("test")
```