# Pygame snake and food collision detection

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

I just decided to learn pygame so I picked up [this](https://www.edureka.co/blog/snake-game-with-pygame/) tutorial.

When I'm in adding the food section, my snake is eating the food but there is no output message. So if statement is not checking for the right values. I tried to change them like foodX - snake_block or foodX + snake_block but there is still no output. Can someone help?

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

#setting up window
screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1080
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")
pygame.display.update()

#colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)

#FPS 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#message function
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    screen.blit(mesg, [screen_width/2, screen_height/2])

#gameloop
def gameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False
    
    #coordinates for snakes starting point
    x1 = screen_width/2
    y1 = screen_height/2

    #for snake movement
    snake_block = 16
    snake_speed = 120
    x1_change = 0       
    y1_change = 0
    
    #food!
    foodX = round(random.randrange(0, screen_width - snake_block) / 10) * 10
    foodY = round(random.randrange(0, screen_height - snake_block) / 10) * 10  
       
    while not game_over:
        
        while game_close == True:
            screen.fill(black)
            message("You Lost! Press ALT + F4 to quit or C to play again", red)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    gameLoop()
                    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
        
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    x1_change = 0
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    x1_change = 0
                    y1_change = +snake_block
                    
        if x1 >= screen_width:       
            x1 = 25
        elif x1 <= 0:
            x1 = screen_width-25
        elif y1 >= screen_height:
            y1 = 25
        elif y1 <= 0:
            y1 = screen_height-25
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [foodX, foodY, snake_block, snake_block])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,white, [x1,y1,snake_block,snake_block])
        pygame.display.update()
        
        if x1 == foodX and y1 == foodY:
            message("Yummy!", red)
        
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
            
    pygame.quit
    quit()
gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907). You have to test if the player rectangle collides with the food rectangle. Use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to detect collision between rectangles:
2. The message is drawn in only a single frame and is therefore barely noticeable. Assign the message text to a variable and draw the message for some time when the variable is set.
3. You have to draw the message text before the display is updated with `pygame.display.update()`

```py
def gameLoop():
    # [...]

    while not game_over:
        # [...]

        player_rect = pygame.Rect(x1,y1,snake_block,snake_block)
        food_rect = pygame.Rect(foodX, foodY, snake_block, snake_block)

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if player_rect.colliderect(food_rect):
            message_text = "Yummy!"
            text_end_time = current_time + 1500 # 1.5 seconds
            foodX = round(random.randrange(0, screen_width - snake_block) / 10) * 10
            foodY = round(random.randrange(0, screen_height - snake_block) / 10) * 10  
        
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, food_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, player_rect)
        if message_text and current_time < text_end_time:
             message(message_text, red)
        pygame.display.update()
        
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
```

[image]