# Pygame when moving into another object the player object should stop

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on this prototype in pygame where you control a square and I'm currently working on collisions with other objects. When the player collides with the object, the player should not be able to move into the object.

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
size = [1000,800]
bg = [0,0,0]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Movement')


class Player:
    def __init__(self,vel,x,y):
        self.vel = vel
        
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.jump = False

    def move(self):
        k = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if k[pygame.K_a]:
            self.x -= self.vel
        if k[pygame.K_d]:
            self.x += self.vel
        if k[pygame.K_w]:
            self.y -= self.vel
        if k[pygame.K_s]:
            self.y += self.vel
  

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,"red",(self.x,self.y,50,50))

    def bordercollsion(self):
        if self.x <=0:
            self.x=0
        if self.x >=950:
            self.x=950
        if self.y <=0:
            self.y=0
        if self.y >=750:
            self.y=750
        
        

    def do(self):
        self.move()
        self.draw()
        self.bordercollsion()
        
    

player = Player(1,500,600)

while True:
    screen.fill(bg)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
                pygame.quit
                sys.exit()
        
    player.do()
    en = pygame.draw.rect(screen,"blue",(10,20,50,50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907). Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect)/[`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to detect collisions of rectangles.

Store the position of the player

```py
player_pos = player.x, player.y
```

Move the palyer:

```py
player.do()
```

Set up a rectangle for the player and the obstacle:

```py
player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, 50, 50)
obstacle_rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 50, 50)
```

Reset the position of the player, when the rectangles collide:

```py
if player_rect.colliderect(obstacle_rect):
    player.x, player.y = player_pos
```

---

Complete application loop

```py
while True:
    screen.fill(bg)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
                pygame.quit
                sys.exit()
        
    player_pos = player.x, player.y
    player.do()
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, 50, 50)
    obstacle_rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 50, 50)
    if player_rect.colliderect(obstacle_rect):
        player.x, player.y = player_pos

    en = pygame.draw.rect(screen,"blue",(10,20,50,50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that someone has already posted a good answer to your question, but my answer has been shoe-horned into your original code.  I've marked my changes with '###' to make them easier to find/identify.

There are a few ways to detect a collision in PyGame; this demonstrates PyGames `colliderect()` method.  There is also a method using sprites and masking.  The method you use depends on what you need.

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
size = [1000,800]
bg = [0,0,0]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Movement')


class Buscemi():    ### new class for the blue square
    '''Blue rectangle with which we must collide!'''    ###
    # def __init__(self):
        # pass
        # Normally you'd have an __init__() method, but this is one of
        #   those unusual cases were we don't actually need one.  It still
        #   returns a Buscemi object
    
    def draw(self):                                             ###
        '''Draws the rectangle and returns the Rect().'''       ###
        return pygame.draw.rect(screen,"blue",(10,20,50,50))    ###


class Player:
    def __init__(self,vel,x,y,buscemi): ### added buscemi argument
        self.vel = vel
        self.buscemi=buscemi    ### blue rectangle

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xold = None    ### for storing x before moving
        self.yold = None    ### for storing y before moving
        self.jump = False
        self.draw()     ### because we need self.dude

    def move(self):
        if not self.dude.colliderect(self.buscemi.draw()):  ### redraw blue and check collision
            k = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            self.xold = self.x  ###
            self.yold = self.y  ###
            if k[pygame.K_a]:
                self.x -= self.vel
            if k[pygame.K_d]:
                self.x += self.vel
            if k[pygame.K_w]:
                self.y -= self.vel
            if k[pygame.K_s]:
                self.y += self.vel
        else:   ### restore x and y
            self.x = self.xold  ###
            self.y = self.yold  ###
  

    def draw(self):
        self.dude = pygame.draw.rect(screen,"red",(self.x,self.y,50,50))    ### named the rectangle

    def bordercollsion(self):
        if self.x <=0:
            self.x=0
        if self.x >=950:
            self.x=950
        if self.y <=0:
            self.y=0
        if self.y >=750:
            self.y=750
        
        

    def do(self):
        self.move()
        self.draw()
        self.bordercollsion()
        
    

en = Buscemi()  ### we need en as an object
player = Player(1,500,600,en)   ### added one more argument

while True:
    screen.fill(bg)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
                pygame.quit
                sys.exit()
        
    # en = pygame.draw.rect(screen,"blue",(10,20,50,50))    ### made a class out of this
    player.do()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_collision(player_rect, obstacle_rect):
    return player_rect.colliderect(obstacle_rect)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why wrap this in a separate function? This doesn't seem very beneficial when the method already exists on the object.

Comment: this is essentially copying the accepted answer: `player_rect.colliderect(obstacle_rect)`

Comment: I'm voting to delete this because it's the same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117137/7758804). Don't add **thank you**, or **confirmation** answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from quality contributions, you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you found helpful. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/35123607)