# How to remove just one sprite from a group when another sprite hits it

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection, collision

well, I'm a beginner at python and I'm trying to create a simple Breakdown game, a have been looking some topics around here bat non of them answer my question, here what a have now, when a ball touches one block the entire line behind it desapear instead of just the one that was hit.

I'm sorry but some of the words in the code aren't english

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self,bolax,bolay):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.image.load("bola.bmp")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = bolax
    self.rect.y = bolay
    self.vel_x,self.vel_y = 5,5

  def movendo(self):

    if self.rect.y == 300 or self.rect.y == 0:
      self.vel_y *= -1
    if self.rect.x == 600 or self.rect.x == 0:
      self.vel_x *= -1

    self.rect.x += self.vel_x
    self.rect.y += self.vel_y

class Pontos(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self,tela,x,y):
    super().__init__()
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(32,12,30,10)
    self.rect.centerx = x
    self.rect.centery = y

class Update():
  def desenhando(tela,peças):
    for peça in peças:
     pygame.draw.rect(tela,(0,0,0),peça)

  def colisão(sprite1,peças):
    for peça in peças:
      gets_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(sprite1, peças)
      if gets_hit:
        bola.vel_y *= -1


#### Geral ####

tela = pygame.display.set_mode((600,300))
peças = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(19):
  for j in range(5):
    ponto = Pontos(tela,i*31 + 20,j*12 + 6)
    peças.add(ponto)

bola = Player(300,150)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

    tela.fill((200,200,200))
    bola.movendo()
    tela.blit(bola.image,(bola.rect.x,bola.rect.y))
    Update.desenhando(tela,peças)
    Update.colisão(bola,peças)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

I just want to remove the sprite that is hit, my problem is here:

def colisão(sprite1,peças):
for peça in peças:
gets_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(sprite1, peças)
if gets_hit:
bola.vel_y *= -1

I don't know how to del just one sprite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually do is to test if the `sprite1` hits any item of `peças`:

> ```py
> for peça in peças:
>    gets_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(sprite1, peças)
> ```

Just test if `peca` hits `sprite1` with [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect):

```py
for peça in peças:
    gets_hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(peça, sprite1)
    if gets_hit:
        peça.kill()
        sprite1.vel_y *= -1
```

However you can simplify the code with [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide):

```py
def colisão(sprite1, peças):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1, peças, True):
        sprite1.vel_y *= -1
```

Also see [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame)