# How to communicate different rectangle positions between classes python

Tags: python

Here I have 2 classes; `Player` and `Obstacle`. `Player` has some basic movement with input from keys. I change `Player.rect.x` to change the position of player. In `Obstacle` I have a code that detects if the `Player.rect.x` reaches the same x postion as `Obstacle.rect.x`, if so print "test".

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        #initializing code

    def movement(self):
        #code for movement

    def update(self):
        self.movement()

class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        #intitializing code

    def test(self):
        player_char = Player() 
        if self.rect.x == player_char.rect.x :
            print("test")

    def update(self):
        self.test()
```

I used print statements to figure out that `player_char.rect.x` changes in the `Player` class but not in the `Obstacle` class. Hence `player_char.rect.x` stays the same as it was when we did move it. `player_char.rect.x` simply doesn't update so the if statement will never become true. How can I update `player_char.rect.x` in `Obstacle` class also?

I am pretty new to python so this might turn out to be a stupid mistake.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question is.  If you want to compare a `Player` object with an `Obstacle` you can overide `__eq__` for example.

Comment: `player_char = Player()` creates a completely new `player` object and does not refer to an existing one. If you want to detect the collision of objects, see [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame)

Comment: Your `test` doesn't look at an existing player.  It creates a BRAND NEW character, and then compares the location.  You would need to pass the player you want to check into `Obstacle.test` so it can fetch the location.  I assume you have a global player object, or maybe a list of players.